Distunguish between USB/BT for the same device
I do some experiments using hidapi lib to read controller/joystick data. Currently I am facing a problem when using PS4 Controller (might be a Problem using other devices too).
On Windows (I guess on Linux too) you can connect the controller via USB and Bluetooth. When enumerating over the devices using hid api lib it detectes the controller twice, one on USB Bus and a second one on BT Bus. The problem is that there is no way to find out which BT device and USB device belongs to each other.
Does have anyone an idea?
EDIT:
first controller
BT:
path    "\\\\?\\HID#{00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&0002054c_PID&09cc#8&12e42c53&4&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}"
vendor_id   1356    
product_id  2508    
serial_number   "dc0c2d6f3597"  
release_number  0
manufacturer_string "Sony Interactive Entertainment"
product_string  "Wireless Controller"
usage_page  1   
usage   5   
interface_number    -1
bus_type    HID_API_BUS_BLUETOOTH 

USB:
path    "\\\\?\\HID#VID_054C&PID_09CC&MI_03#9&2a666ca3&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}"
vendor_id   1356
product_id  2508
serial_number   ""
release_number  256 
manufacturer_string "Sony Interactive Entertainment"
product_string  "Wireless Controller"   
usage_page  1   
usage   5   
interface_number    3   
bus_type    HID_API_BUS_USB

second controller
BT:
path     "\\\\?\\HID#{00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&0002054c_PID&09cc#8&2e3024ab&1&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}" 
vendor_id   1356
product_id  2508
serial_number   "dc0c2d6be031"  
release_number  0   
manufacturer_string "Sony Interactive Entertainment"
product_string  "Wireless Controller"
usage_page  1   
usage   5   
interface_number    -1
bus_type    HID_API_BUS_BLUETOOTH 

USB:
path    "\\\\?\\HID#VID_054C&PID_09CC&MI_03#a&150a354e&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}"
vendor_id   1356
product_id  2508
serial_number   ""
release_number  256
manufacturer_string "Sony Interactive Entertainment"
product_string  "Wireless Controller"
usage_page  1
usage   5
interface_number    3
bus_type    HID_API_BUS_USB


There is a way to find a Bluetooth one by checking that the device's MAC in in the device's path (using SetupAPI and Registry). I use this method to find Wii Remote connected as HID device (by MAC).


I can't do that because it must work on windows/linux. 2. I checked the path which is completely different between usb and bt (testet with two controllers both connected via USB and BT). There is nothing which is equal or I can extract and compare to. 3. The Mac addresse are different between USB and BT and after reconnect too.


Added hid api output. except for the uuid I cant see anything that is comparable. The uuid is the same for ALL PS4 controllers. I guess serial number would the winner but its empty for USB

I have no idea how to do it on Linux, but I described how ti must be done on Windows. You MUST use SetupAPI (not HID) to find all PS4 HID devices (by VID/PID) and the use Registry drivers entries to find a full device object ID string which contains the MAC. That works perfect with Bluetooth HID devices.

You could add the outputs for the 2nd controller. You have the productid, and also the last guid from the path that are identical. Can you share the code? Interface -1 could mean it's not connected?

added second controller output

the output is what hidapi provides. the last uuid is the same for ALL controllers. I can not rely on the path because this is really platform dependend

I found a solution.
there is a unique triple vendor_id, product_id and serial_number. If it is the same device it does have the same ids. Bluetooth seems to sends a serial number every time (at least with all other controllers I tested) while USB is rarely set. For DualShock 4 there is a report to obtain the MAC address which is similar to the serial number
struct ReportFeatureInMacAll {
    uint8_t ReportID = 0x12;  // (0x09 for BT)
    uint8_t ClientMac[6];
    uint8_t Hard08;
    uint8_t Hard25;
    uint8_t Hard00;
    uint8_t HostMac[6];
  }
  auto dev = hid_open_path(hidDeviceInfo->path);
  ReportFeatureInMacAll report;
  hid_get_feature_report(dev, (uint8_t *)&report, sizeof(report));
  hid_close(dev);

Now I am able to distinguish between them.
